# how would i make a menu bar item in tkinter that shows the hotkey that goes with it?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have been wondering how to do I would I show a menu bar item with a hotkey that goes along with it.

[image]

I know how to make a menu bar item I just need help with adding the hotkey that goes with it in.

Sorry for not explaining my question very well, I don't explain well.

Comment: Try `accelerator` option of `add_command()`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `accelerator` option.

```
from tkinter import *
   
root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New",accelerator="Ctrl+N")
filemenu.add_command(label="Open",accelerator="Crtl+O")
filemenu.add_command(label="Save",accelerator="Ctrl+S")

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)


root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the output:

[image]